# First react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Alright, so this is the first react code that I wrote. The "Hello world" code.

However, it doesn't seem to be working. I've tried some answers but none of them worked for me.

Here is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">

        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.5.4/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script>
            ReactDOM.render(
                React.DOM.h1(null, "Hello World!"),
                document.getElementById("app")
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the error that I get at console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'purgeUnmountedComponents' of undefined
    at clearHistory (react-dom.js:8499)
    at resetMeasurements (react-dom.js:8542)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.onBeginFlush (react-dom.js:8712)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.initializeAll (react-dom.js:14848)
    at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (react-dom.js:14815)
    at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (react-dom.js:9835)
    at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (react-dom.js:14816)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (react-dom.js:8862)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (react-dom.js:12944)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (react-dom.js:10029)
```

Comment: Could just be the `.` between `React` and `DOM` in the render call. It should just be `ReactDOM.render()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is, you are using minified version of `react` and un-minified version of `react-dom`, use either minified or not minified.

Use these references (both minified `react` and `react-dom`), it will work:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Or these both not minified:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

Run this snippet, check the working example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">

        </div>
        
        <script>
            ReactDOM.render(
                React.DOM.h1(null, "Hello World!"),
                document.getElementById("app")
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the minified and unminified versions of react and react-dom. Choose what version you need (minified or not) and use it in both scripts.